# GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On Facebook GraphAPI, with the Python SDK, I am trying to send a notification to a user. I receive the error:

```
GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
```

My Python code is:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=TOKENS["app_token"])
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='notifications', template='Tell us how you like the app!', href='https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: You can not use `/me` with an app access token. You need to use the app-scoped user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=TOKENS["user_token"]) 
user_info= graph.get_object(id='me', fields='id')  
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=TOKENS["app_token"])
graph.put_object(parent_object= user_info['id'], connection_name='notifications', template='Tell us how you like the app!', href='https://www.google.com')
```